# when inserting a doctype html content will not show

Tags: html, xhtml, dtd

I had problem in showing my html/css document in internet explorer,it is working well in fire fox and chrome,so I guess that it is because I didn't insert any doctype,when I insert the doctype of xhtml or html it is not working,it will show just my header section,what should I include for doctype?

I tried this one:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and it is not working.here is my code which is working:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<title>bazar</title>
<style type="text/css">

#container {
width: 770px;
margin: 0 auto
}
#main
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
up:0;
bottom:0;
margin:0;
}
#header
{
position:fixed;
background:url(header_slice.png);
repeat x;
width:100%;
height:63px;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
#logo
{
position:fixed;
background:url(logo.png);
width:192;
height:59;
float:right;
left:900;
}
#mymenu
{
position:fixed;
background:url(menu.png);
width:302;
height:19;
top:30;
left:122.5;
overflow:auto;
}
#mytext
{
position:fixed;
background:url(textbox.png);
width:257;
height:20;
top:30;
left:460;
}
#nav{
position:absolute;
background:url(navigation_slice.jpg);
repeat x;
width:100%;
height:148;
top:63;
z-index:1000;
left:0;
right:0;
}
#mycontainer
{
position:absolute;
background:white;
repeat x;
repeat y;
width:100%;
height:1281;
top:210;
left:0;
right:0;
}
#menu2
{
position:absolute;
background:url(navbar.png);
repeat x;
width:952;
height:67;
top:40;
left:125;
}
#home
{
position:absolute;
background:url(home.png);
width:52;
height:36;
top:30;
left:0;
}
#pencil{
position:absolute;
background:url(pencil.png);
width:39;
height:42;
top:7;
right:23;
}
#archive{
position:absolute;
background:url(archive.png);
width:38;
height:37;
top:7;
right:110;
}
#sep1{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:78;
}
#sep2{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:173;
}
#sep3{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:284;
}
#sep4{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:388;
}
#sep4{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:459;
}
#sep4{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:386;
}
#sep5{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:459;
}
#sep6{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:526;
}
#sep7{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:596;
}
#sep8{
position:absolute;
repeat y;
width:2;
height:67;
top:0;
right:670;
}
.sep{
background:url(sep.png);
}
#seminar
{
position:absolute;
background:url(seminar.png);
right:204;
width:45;
height:33;
top:7;
}
#learn
{
position:absolute;
background:url(learning.png);
right:312;
width:44;
height:36;
top:7;
}
#art{
position:absolute;
background:url(art.png);
width:45;
height:40;
top:5;
right:400;
}
#engineer{
position:absolute;
background:url(engineer.png);
width:54;
height:36;
top:7;
right:470;
}
#publish{
position:absolute;
background:url(publish.png);
width:49;
height:38;
top:7;
right:539;
}
#new{
position:absolute;
background:url(new.png);
width:36;
height:31;
top:7;
right:610;
}
#contact
{
position:absolute;
background:url(contact.png);
width:178;
height:58;
top:17;
right:610;
left:125;
}
#rect1
{
width:716;
height:308;
top:-35;
left:125;
}
#rect2
{
width:226;
height:308;
top:-35;
left:850;
}
.rect
{
position:absolute;
background:url(rect.png);
repeat x;
repeat y;
}
#special
{position:absolute;
background:url(special.png);
width:696;
height:255;
top:-30;
left:132;
z-index:1000;
}
#chasb
{
position:absolute;
background:url(chasb.png);
width:56;
height:62;
top:50;
right:300;
z-index:1000;
}


#takhte
{
position:absolute;
background:url(takhte.png);
width:51;
height:58;
top:170;
right:300;
z-index:1000;
}
#sabad1{
position:absolute;
width:80;
height:17;
top:210;
right:370;
z-index:1000;
}
#sabad2{
position:absolute;
width:80;
height:17;
top:90;
right:370;
z-index:1000;
}
.sabad
{
background:url(sabad.png);
}

#left
{
position:absolute;
background:url(slideleft.png);
top:280;
left:125;
width:20;
height:69;
z-index:2000;
}
#right
{
position:absolute;
background:url(slideright.png);
top:280;
left:822;
width:17;
height:69;
z-index:2000;
}
#slide
{
position:absolute;
top:280;
left:125;
width:716;
height:69;
z-index:1500;
}
#staff
{
position:absolute;
background:url(staff.png);
width:228;
height:70;
top:280;
z-index:1000;
left:850;
}
#mybox
{
position:absolute;
background-color: white;
top:0;
left:865;
width:200;
height:260;
z-index:900;
}
#product
{
position:absolute;
background:url(products.png);
width:200;
height:76;
top:-30;
left:865;
z-index:1000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='main'>
<div id='header'>
<div id='logo'></div>
<div id='mymenu'></div>
<div id='mytext'></div>
<div id='nav'>
<div id='menu2'>
        <div id='home'></div><div id="pencil"></div>
        <div id="sep1" class="sep"></div><div id="archive"></div>
        <div id="sep2" class="sep"></div><div id="seminar"></div>
        <div id="sep3" class="sep"></div><div id="learn"></div>
        <div id="sep4" class="sep"></div><div id="art"></div>
        <div id="sep5" class="sep"></div><div id="engineer"></div>
        <div id="sep6" class="sep"></div><div id="publish"></div>
        <div id="sep7" class="sep"></div><div id="new"></div><div id="sep8" class="sep"></div>
</div>
<div id='contact'></div>
</div>

</div>

<div id='mycontainer'>

<div id='rect1' class='rect'></div>
<div id='rect2' class='rect'></div>
<div id='special'></div>
<div id='chasb'></div><div id='takhte'></div><div id='sabad1' class="sabad"></div><div id='sabad2' class="sabad"></div>
<div id='mybox'></div>
<div id='product'></div>
<div id='staff'></div>
<div id='slide' class="rect"></div>
<div id='left'></div><div id='right'></div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

as I said by including doctype it will just show the header

Comment: What version of internet explorer?  The problem could also be in your css and you should include that as well.

Comment: I want it to work in all browsers,my ie is version 8

Comment: At least you need to close the meta tags, like />, and you need to set a type to your style, like <style type="text/css">

Comment: Did you make this in Dreamweaver or something? Why are all of your elements absolutely positioned?

Comment: I am converting a psd file to css and html no I didn't make it in dream weaver

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 1):

The page has a large number of CSS errors. When you have no doctype, the page is processed in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), which means that browsers emulate old, broken versions of IE. Adding a doctype broke this. For example, any length expressions without unit, except 0, are ignored then.

You need to decide whether you wish to fix (or rewrite) the code to comply with HTML and CSS specifications or to play with Quirks Mode.

Answer (score 0):

The only DOCTYPE that should be used is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I suspect that it is the lack of units. I'd guess that IE doesn't use the default value of `px` here.

`width`, `height`, `left` and `top` should all have units, try adding a `px` onto each of those. `z-index` doesn't need that of course.